# how do i navigate in the terminal

Tags: command-line, directory, root, repository

i am new to linux and i am confused on how to navigate to and from between `root@2c00d30f31ad:/` and `root@2c00d30f31ad:~#`

Here is what i am facing:

```
root@2c00d30f31ad:/alx-pre_course# cd                                                                                                                                                   
root@2c00d30f31ad:~# cd alx-pre_course                                                                                                                                                  
bash: cd: alx-pre_course: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                     
root@2c00d30f31ad:~#
```

Comment: you can change directory using: cd directory_name/

Comment: i am still not clear, i have tried but still no success

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this? Your prompt suggests you are logged in as the root user. `cd alx-pre_course` will only work if the alx-pre_course directory is contained in the current directory. In the terminal dialogue you have shown you seem to start from `/alx-pre_course` so to get back there it’s `cd /alx-pre_course`. The `ls` command will list what ever is in the current directory

Comment: thank you i have manage to start navigating with this clarification

Answer (score 0):

You should've search for Linux basic commands, this a quick one https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal
And for your question it's because of the directory is not in your location you can use `ls` to list and `cd` to navigate to destination and `cd ..` to step back.

Edit: At the first line you were already in it you just need to list ,and when you type cd you went to your home directory but the directory is in /

Comment: thanks i managed to navigate, its working